# R Shiny: actionButton to generate random value from input values and render plot

Tags: r, shiny

I have made a simple shiny app that generates a plot of the x and y data from an individual group within the data which the users can choose from. The app subsets the larger dataframe and produces the graph for only the chosen individual. I would also like to include and actionButton which chooses an individual from within the dataset at random and plots that every time the button is pushed.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Create example data frame
Data <- data.frame(Indiv = c(rep(1,10),
                                rep(2,10),
                                rep(3,10),
                                rep(4,10),
                                rep(5,10),
                                rep(6,10)),
                      varX = c(runif(10, min = 1, max = 10),
                               runif(10, min = 1, max = 10),
                               runif(10, min = 1, max = 10),
                               runif(10, min = 1, max = 10),
                               runif(10, min = 1, max = 10),
                               runif(10, min = 1, max = 10)),
                      varY = c(runif(10, min = 1, max = 1),
                               runif(10, min = 1, max = 5),
                               runif(10, min = 1, max = 10),
                               runif(10, min = 1, max = 15),
                               runif(10, min = 1, max = 20),
                               runif(10, min = 1, max = 25))
                          )
######   Shiny App   #######
# User interface for shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Random Select Button"), # page title
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel 
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # input for which TagID to display in plot
      actionButton("do", "Plot Random Indiv"),
      selectInput(inputId = "ID",
                  label = "Individual ID",
                  choices = levels(factor(Data$Indiv)), 
                  selected = NULL, # choose no individuals by default
                  multiple = FALSE     # allow for multiple options
      ),
      p("Choose an invidual, or push the button to randomly choose an individual."),
      
    ),
    # Main Panel
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("IndivPlot"), # name of plot object
    ),
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Plot
  output$IndivPlot <- renderPlot({ # make a live adjustable plot
    
    ### Filter to only include selected Individual
    Data <- Data[Data$Indiv %in% input$ID,] 
    
    # Create plot
    p = ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=varX, y=varY))+
      geom_line()+
      expand_limits(y=c(1,30), x = c(1,10))+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1,30,5), labels=seq(1,30,5))+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,10,1), labels = seq(1,10,1))+ 
      labs(x = "My X", y = "My Y")  
    print(p)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I can't figure out how to get the action button to randomly choose and individual ID number and cause the plot to render. Right now, the button exists on the UI but doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a reactive ID which will be dynamic. It will be updated when the ID is selected from the dropdown as well as when the action button is pressed to generate random ID.

The plot will be updated based on the ID.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

######   Shiny App   #######
# User interface for shiny app
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Random Select Button"), # page title
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel 
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # input for which TagID to display in plot
      actionButton("do", "Plot Random Indiv"),
      selectInput(inputId = "ID",
                  label = "Individual ID",
                  choices = levels(factor(Data$Indiv)), 
                  selected = NULL, # choose no individuals by default
                  multiple = FALSE     # allow for multiple options
      ),
      p("Choose an invidual, or push the button to randomly choose an individual."),
      
    ),
    # Main Panel
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("IndivPlot"), # name of plot object
    ),
  )
)

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  #To save dynamic ID
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    #ID selected from the dropdown manually
    rv$ID <- input$ID
  })
  # Plot
  output$IndivPlot <- renderPlot({ # make a live adjustable plot
    ### Filter to only include selected Individual
    Data <- Data[Data$Indiv %in% rv$ID,] 
    
    # Create plot
    p = ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=varX, y=varY))+
      geom_line()+
      expand_limits(y=c(1,30), x = c(1,10))+
      scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(1,30,5), labels=seq(1,30,5))+
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,10,1), labels = seq(1,10,1))+ 
      labs(x = "My X", y = "My Y")  
    print(p)
  })

  #On action button click
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    #Select a random ID
    rv$ID <- sample(unique(Data$Indiv), 1)
    #Update the value of dropdown with random ID selected
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "ID",
                      label = "Individual ID",
                      choices = levels(factor(Data$Indiv)), 
                      selected = rv$ID)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you! This is what I assumed needed to happen, but I couldn't figure out the logic to make it work. Thank you.